# How to add Facebook page iframe in instant article view?

Tags: facebook-instant-articles

I have a Facebook page for my online magazine (news) site which was developed by Wordpress. I have successfully enabled Facebook Instant Article by using Wordpress instant article plugin and using Facebook audience network to earn money by running ads from Facebook. I am trying to display my Facebook page iFrame box in instant article layout to get more likes. I read a few articles about it but not getting any clue to how I can add it in the layout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From Instant Articles team here.

You shouldn't use the IFrame solution to show a Facebook Page within your Instant Articles to increase your Likes into that page. The best way of achieving this is by using the CTA for likes we have.

You can find more info about that here: [CTA Page Likes](https://www.facebook.com/help/publisher/146679892685953)

Comment: Thanks a lot, @Everton! I did it after following facebook CTA documentation. It's working fine!